Why does rsync say "cannot delete non-empty directory", when I haven't specified "--delete"?
I am trying to build an rsync command to back up my $HOME directory (under Ubuntu Studio 24.04.2 LTS) to an existing copy (created manually from earlier releases) on my NAS.
Here is my experimental command line:
rsync -av --update --acls --xattrs --atimes --dry-run --whole-file --exclude='*cache*' --log-file=rsync.log $HOME/ /nas/home/

As you can see, I have (intentionally) not specified "--delete".
Why then do I get "cannot delete non-empty directory" immediately after "building file list" in the log file?

Thanks to --itemize-changes I figured out what was going on.  rsync was trying to delete a directory in the target directory in order to replace it with a symlink from the source. Fortunately, the directory it was trying to delete was obsolete, but I am still glad I tried rsync with --dry-run first. ;-}
